# Can anyone help me with this xcode issue?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to get my app to display properly on the iPad as when I run it the text position;

```
label.position = CGPointMake(-180, -135);
```

Which is set for the iPhone res position but of course when running on the iPad the position is completely off (still in the same place for the iPhone one).

Is there anything I can add for it to auto resize the position if an iPad is detected?

The full code I have atm is as follows!;

```
SKLabelNode *label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Helvetica"];
label.fontSize = 14;
label.fontColor = [SKColor yellowColor];
label.text = @"-Shield Power-";
label.position = CGPointMake(-180, -135);
label.alpha = 1;
[self addChild:label];
```

Comment: just make the label position with respect to self.frame.origin.x

Comment: I am not familiar with spritekit. But in Cocos 2D, we have to set AnyObject.Positiontype = yourpositiontype. Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have, somehow, to detect if you are running on an iPad or an iPhone. Then implement an if statement for the position.

```
  UIDevice* thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if(thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        // iPad
    }
    else
    {
        // iPhone
    }
```

That being said, you could also try autolayout and constraints. You can have two storyboards (one for each device) and set views separately.

Comment: This comment appeared while I was testing the other one, This works perfectly thank you very much! <3

Comment: No problem. Glad to be helpful.

Comment: Hey Marcal I've just ran into another issue... Now I have positions for the iPad and iPhone at 3.5inch it's still then out for the 4inch versions! Nightmare or what for a newbie! There only seems to be UIUserInterfaceIdionPad and Phone versions is there a 3rd option for the other phone size at all?

Comment: Found it! In the end I had to use this CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

   if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       if (screenSize.height > 480.0f) {
           /*Do iPhone 5 stuff here.*/
       } else {
           /*Do iPhone Classic stuff here.*/
       }
   } else {
       /*Do iPad stuff here.*/
   }

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the CGGeometry class - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html - this will enable you to do things like:

```
CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
```

and

```
CGRectGetMinY(self.view.frame);
```

And then construct X and Y co-ordinates for your CGPoint, e.g.

```
CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.frame)-180,CGRectGetMinY(self.view.frame)-135);
```

or using percentages so that everything happens in a dynamic way, like this:

```
CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.frame)-CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)*0.5,CGRectGetMinY(self.view.frame)-CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)*0.3);
```

Comment: Cheers for the replies guys very much appreciated, I've just tried using what you suggested but the text now keeps to the middle of the screen on both iPhone and iPad with no matter what value I change the -180/-135 too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check which frame you are referencing. Here's some basic sample code to demonstrate that it works `UIView *blue = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.frame)-CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)*0.5, CGRectGetMinY(self.view.frame)-CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)*0.3, 100, 100)];
    blue.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:blue];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{blue.center=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.frame)+CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)*0.5, CGRectGetMinY(self.view.frame)+CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)*0.3);}];`